# React call function in class component from exported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call handleChange in my BasicInfos component from the Cropper function.
Here's an example code:

```
export default function Cropper() {
  return (
    <Crop onChange={handleChange}/> // I want to call handleChange from here
  );
}

import Cropper from "./Cropper";

@observer
class BasicInfos extends React.Component
{
   @action
   handleChange = (blob, url) => {
      tmpFile = blob;
      tmpFilePath = url;
   }
   render () {
     return (
       <Cropper action={this.handleChange}/>
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you get `blob, url`?

Comment: It was just an example, there is another function that made them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to call the handleChange function from the Cropper function, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the prop action

```
export default function Cropper({action}) {
  return (
    <Crop onChange={action}/> // I want to call handleChange from here
  );
}

import Cropper from "./Cropper";

@observer
class BasicInfos extends React.Component
{
   @action
   handleChange = (blob, url) => {
      tmpFile = blob;
      tmpFilePath = url;
   }
   render () {
     return (
       <Cropper action={this.handleChange}/>
     );
   }
}
```